# How can I determine the number of pixels drawn within a predefined shape on the screen?

Tags: xna, c#

[image]

In the image above, I want to know how can I calculate the number of pixels of the rendered players' shadows that are inside the elephant outline.

An occlusion query is used to count the number of pixels occluded in the entire screen, but I want to restrict my count to just the number of pixels that end up inside the outline.

Comment: Can you use a snap shot? Break the shape to triangles? What tools do you have at your disposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

1. Render the player's shadows to a render target.
2. Render the shape to a render target.
3. For each pixel, determine if it both (A) contains a shape pixel and (B) contains a player shadow pixel.

Comment: yes, that's what I've done on that moment, thank you :)